# Angular 2 css binding: style.width and style.height

Tags: css, html, angular, canvas, html5-canvas

I got some strange render using plain html5 canvas and css binding with A2.

To sum up, what is the difference between:

```
<canvas height="400" width="1200" #background>
</canvas>
```

AND

```
<canvas #background [style.width.px]="device.xaGuiData.sizeX" [style.height.px]="device.xaGuiData.sizeY">
</canvas>
```

where device.xaGuiData.sizeX and device.xaGuiData.sizeY are equals to 400 and 1200.

Here the code i use to display an image:

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://localhost:4201/' + this.device.xaGuiData.imageName1;
img.onload = function () {
  myCtxBackground.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

The render is good using the first solution.

When i use the second one, the result is stretched and ****** up.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thx in advance for any advices or solutions.

Comment: Can you give us some more clues? How does the width/height properties look in the dev tools when you compare the approaches? Any more relevant code you can show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please use attr.width and attr.height like given below.**

```html
<canvas #background [attr.width]="device.xaGuiData.sizeX" [attr.height]="device.xaGuiData.sizeY">
</canvas>
```